Why malloc return a very higher address than user space and not in /proc/pid/maps?
I have a demo that run in Android 13 with linux Linux version 5.15.41.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int print(const char *parr)
{
        if (nullptr != parr)
                std::cout << parr << "\n\n";

        return 0;
}

class AA {
        int a=55;
        int b=4;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* env[])
{
        int var_a = 1;
        char arr[] = {"ABCDEF"};
        AA * aa = new AA();
        AA  aa2;
        printf("aa AA  %p\n",aa);
        printf("&aa %p\n", &aa);
        printf("aa2 AA %p\n", aa2);
        printf("&aa2 %p\n", &aa2);
        int *p=(int*)sbrk(0);
        printf("sbrk %p\n", p);
        int* p2=(int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
        printf("malloc %p\n", p2);
        int ret = print("hello world");

        std::cout << arr << "\n\n";
        std::cout << "var_a=" << var_a << "\n\n";
        std::cout << "ret=" << ret << "\n\n";

        return 0;
}

The output is
aa AA  0xb400007391409010                               
&aa 0x7fe8582b00
aa2 AA 0x400000037
&aa2 0x7fe8582af8
sbrk 0x6263db1000
malloc 0xb400007391406060
hello world                                             
ABCDEF

var_a=1

ret=0

The new AA() and malloc return a very high address, 0xb400007391409010  0xb400007391406060  much larger than normal user space address 0x0000 00 00 00 00 00 00 ~ 0x0000 7F FF FF FF FF FF
And that address does not exist in /proc/pid/maps.
We know malloc use brk and mmap,  the brk pointer is low sbrk 0x6263db1000, not exptected as well.
So How we should understand this, Anyone can give some clue and reference?
Thanks
